# Spring Data JPA Repository Interface Implementaion

Tags: spring, jpa, repository, spring-data

I have my repository defined as below:

```
 public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
      List<Long> findAllItemsForUser(String user);
 }
```

I also have an implementation for this as I wanted to use a native SQL query:

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<MyClass, Long> implements MyRepository {

 @PersistenceContext
 EntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository repository;

  ...
  public List<Long> findAllItemsForUser(String user)
  {
      String sql = "select m.id from ..."; //Complex SQL Query here with several joins;
      List<Long> list = (List<Long>)entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter(1,user).getResultList();

      return list;
  }
  ...
  }
```

Now, I want to use this output list of ids using Spring Data JPA's standard `findByIdIn` clause. I tried adding a method in my interface with this. It then required me to implement the same.

I implemented it as follows, but it throws an exception orginating at repository.findByIdIn() in the implementation below:

```
@Override
public List<MyClass> findByIdIn(List<Long> idList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return repository.findByIdIn(idList);
}
```

I

```
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at $Proxy140.findByIdIn(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: There are some lines missing in the stacktrace. can you please add these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I ended with is a separate set of interfaces - One with pure JPA interfaces and one with Custom JDBC implementation. It appears Spring is not able to derive method name based queries when an Implementation exists.

Hence, using separate interfaces seems to be the only way out.

Answer (score 0):

Inject an instance of the interface `MyRepository` into `MyRepositoryImpl`, and then use that injected instance to invoke `findByIdIn`.

(You must not implement `findByIdIn` in `MyRepositoryImpl`)

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<MyClass, Long>
                           implements MyRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository repository;

  ...
  public List<Long> findAllItemsForUser(String user) {
      ...
      return repository.findByIdIn(...)    // <----
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I added the findByIdIn method to my interface and my Impl is throwing this error in IDE: _The type MyRepositoryImpl must implement the inherited abstract method MyRepository.findByIdIn(List<Long>)_